# read,write,modify while texteditor is open

Tags: c#

after one hour searching I'm writing this question.
how to read,write and modify a text in text editor while the text editor is open, the text editor might be anything such as notepad or vs or word.
the type of c# application isn't matter whatever it be.

Comment: "modify a text in text editor while the text editor is open": is this what you mean ?

Comment: This question is very generic. Are you asking about using text editor itself to modify text, i.e. via its macros OR simple file manipulation on disk? In case of former, you need to specify which editor you're considering and check if it supports macros.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : yes

Comment: @Sherlock : as i explained for every text editor,here we want to create a solution for every text editor that's the point.

Comment: Sorry but I can't make sense of the sentence. To modify text in an editor, well, yes, the editor must be opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to another memory's process is more complex and less stable. Better idea is to send a message/event to another process. [This](http://www.codingvision.net/miscellaneous/c-send-text-to-notepad) link demonstrates it for notepad, but idea is similar for other editors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the process, it involves a lot of Windows API and it is different for different applications. My advise, don't do it, I cannot imagine an architecture which includes this kind of actions, it is asking for bugs.

But, if you still want to do it, Google: "connect to a process notepad and change text  c#"

You will find many links which explain. For example this one:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670373/Csharp-Read-Write-Another-Process-Memory

Comment: thanks for answer, i was thinking c# program may send select all and copy text command to that editor ,this way our program might have the entire text and then for modify we can send it to text editor again